# Why is Cobertura not working in my Spring/Hibernate Webapp?

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, cobertura, java-bytecode-asm

I want to use Cobertura code coverage recording in my web application, but can't get it to work. I suspect, the problem is some conflict between Spring or Hibernate and Cobertura since all three use the ASM lib to do their byte code manipulation.

I did the following:

- I used the Cobertura Ant task to instrument my jars in "WEB-INF/lib" and generated the  "cobertura.ser" file
- I added the "cobertura.jar" to "WEB-INF/lib"
- I start tomcat providing cobertura file location (net.sourceforge.cobertura.datafile=cobertura.ser)

When I start Tomcat, I get the following error message when the Spring context is initialized:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.foo.MyClass.setInstance($Proxy28)
  at com.foo.common.runtime.spring.PluginInjector.findBestMatchingMethod(PluginInjector.java:252)
  at com.foo.common.runtime.spring.PluginInjector.invokeMethod(PluginInjector.java:198)
  at com.foo.common.runtime.spring.PluginInjector.afterPropertiesSet(PluginInjector.java:174)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
```

I'm already aware, that the asm.jar that comes with cobertura should not be in the classpath and therefore I only copied cobertura.jar to WEB-INF\lib.

Besides, I also tried Emma and it worked. However, cobertura looks more modern, active (last update from 2010 instead of 2005) and generates nicer reports so I would prefer it over Emma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make two changes, to make this work:

1. I had to set `proxy-target-class="true"` in the Spring configuration, so Spring uses CGLIB to generate proxies instead of using JDK dynamic proxies (see [Spring Proxying mechanisms](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch08s06.html)).
2. I had to set the JVM Parameter `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier`, which causes the JVM to use the old byte code verifier. This seems to be necessary since Cobertura's byte code manipulation is incompatible with Java 7.